# How to know changing data of postgresql in last 5 seconds

Tags: android, postgresql, odoo-8

I am developing an Odoo 8 (OpenERP) application. That application use postgresql database. In backend of Odoo 8, there is **add sale order** button. So, I want to know, how to know the changing data in the last 5 seconds? My need is I want to insert data from mobile apps. What tables that that changing? Any query for do that? Or another suggest. 
the database has 314 tables. Is there application of part3 like MONYog may be?
Any help is very appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of situation, there is one best way to manage as

Use always two columns in each table as "CreatedOn" and "LastUpdatedOn", and insert proepr values in it as on create time add current time in both then on every update just change last updated on by current time so you will easily get data as per your requirement.

Comment: as you know the database has 314 tables. Beside that I am not allowed to add the column for that db. Is there application of part3 like MONYog may be?

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a function like this:

```
create or replace function notify_table_change() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
NOTIFY all_writes TG_RELNAME;
IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN RETURN OLD; ELSE RETURN NEW; END OF;
$$;
```

Then you could add the trigger for all inserts, updates, and deletes (but not truncate since I didn't handle that).

Then te client can:

```
 LISTEN all_writes;
```

And will get live notifications of which tables are updated in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring database feels a bit strange approach to the problem. Writing custom modules for odoo (and OpenERP) is very simple and staightforward. I'd create module which triggers whatever you want to do.

Here is a brief example of simplest OpenERP / odoo module:

```
from osv import osv
class my_custom_module(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _name = 'sale.order'

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, ctx={}):
        <your code here, whatever you want to do when new sale.order obejcet is created >
        return super(my_custom_module, self).create(cr, uid, vals, ctx)
    my_custom_module()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

In a live commercial  app. The method I use is a **creation** and **update** date/time stamp column.

Example

```
create table foo (
foo_id serial not null unique, 
created_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp, 
updated_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp
) with oids;
```

The trigger to do the work

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_table_to_do_update
--What i want to do
```

The trigger on the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update_foo
AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.updated_timestamp IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.updated_timestamp)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_table__to_do_update();
```

Anything else can put an unnecessary overhead on the system.

All the best